Questions of another user now appear as if asked by me
Shortly after I asked this question I received an email update and I found out that another question asked in another group by another user now appears as if it was asked by me.
What is happening?

You're better off using the Contact form  because this needs Staff to sort out. Nothing we or you can do about this. Note that this is not a single incident: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399562

My immediate thought is that your account has been merged with that of another user (i.e. the one who originally asked those questions). Whether that was an accident, a glitch, or a deliberate action, I can't say; as rene said, your best bet is probably to contact support.

@F1Krazy is most likely correct, there were recently several cases of accidental merges, and as SE did not say anything, they most likely did not do anything to prevent it from happening again. Sadly nothing we can do, and manual fix of those things take long weeks.

@F1Krazy Merges are at the account level - meaning it's impossible to merge two user profiles on a single site without merging them network-wide. Regardless, as stated, only staff can merge accounts because they are risky from a PII standpoint. Accounts are generally only merged by request from the owner, automatically by the system due to PII overlap, or manually by staff due to clear evidence of account abuse - most cases of  which are handled by merely deleting the problematic profile rather than merging. While uncommon, errors can occur in the review process.

@FluidCode did you submit a contact form? Did you get any reply from staff?
